# Backbone: RESTful backend in GAE

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to write a backend for Backbone using Google App Engine's Java backend, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. I have been using doGet() and doPost() for App Engine, but how do you handle this with the other two?

What parameters do you pass to the servlet, what does the servlet look like in terms of functions and mapping, and what do they return? Backbone seems to complicate GAE, and I can't find much else on how to do this.

Comment: have you tried overriding doPut and doDelete?  Those are defined in HttpServlet along with goGet and goPost.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Comment: Oops, derp on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're extending HttpServlet, you will be able to override goPut and doDelete the same as goGet and doPost.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html